# Simple addition in Perl causing result to be off by small fraction

Tags: perl, math, addition, floating-accuracy

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

  $a = 1;

  while ( $a <= 50 ) {
    print "$a\n";
    $a += 0.025;
  }
```

Very simple code.

But here is how the output looks like...

```
2.225
2.25
2.275
2.3
2.325
2.35
2.375
2.4
2.42499999999999
2.44999999999999
2.47499999999999
2.49999999999999
2.52499999999999
2.54999999999999
2.57499999999999
```

Everything was fine until 2.42499999999999.

```
4.32499999999999
4.34999999999999
4.37499999999999
4.4
4.425
4.45
4.475
4.5
```

Then back to normal.

And it keeps alternating between what one would expect, and being off by a small fraction.

What's causing this?

```
49.8249999999982
49.8499999999982
49.8749999999982
49.8999999999982
49.9249999999982
49.9499999999982
49.9749999999982
49.9999999999982
```

Comment: More information about rounding errors in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEFVQaSgJ60&ab_channel=CurtisPoe) talk.

Comment: 25/1000 is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal. As such, saving it accurately as a floating point number would require inifite storage. Every time you add the value, you introduce a little bit of error. One alterative: `my $x = 1000; while ($x < 50_000) { say $x/1000; $x += 25; }`